# Como seleccionar aleatoriamente un numero añadido a un List<Integer> ???? = new ArrayList<Integer>();

Tags: java

Ante todo agradezco el tiempo que se tomen ayudándome en esta gestión, soy bastante nuevo en esto del java y demás y tengo la siguiente situación:

```
int id = 0;        
Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
    id = Integer.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
    numeros.add(id);
}
```

En este caso estoy añadiendo a mi lista el valor de la columna 0 de mi jTable1,el for se cumple sin ningún problema pero yo quiero que después de terminar el for me seleccione uno de esos valores que le añadí a la lista pero al azar.

Ejemplo: en este caso los valores que se cargan la variable id son: 8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1.

justo en ese orden se agregan a la lista y yo lo que quiero es seleccionar aleatoriamente uno de esos datos, que una vez, sea el 7 y otra el 4 y así sucesivamente.

Answer (score 2):

Así se genera un número aleatorio entre 0 y el tamaño de la lista menos 1 (se excluye el tope por eso no hace falta restarle 1):

```
int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numeros.size());
```

Aquí te muestro como ir sacando los elementos de la lista aleatoriamente en un ciclo hasta que quede vacía:

```
while(!numeros.isEmpty()) {
    int randomIndex = random.nextInt(numeros.size());
    System.out.println("Numero en [" + randomIndex + "]: " + numeros.get(randomIndex));
    numeros.remove(randomIndex);
}
```

Comment: Muchisimas Gracias hermano, agradezco mucho tu tiempo y tu ayuda.

era justo lo que necesitaba, agradezco de nuevo tu tiempo.

Comment: @AndresRincon No olvides de aceptar la respuesta que te sirvió.

Answer (score 0):

Para obtener un elemento aleatorio de tu array de enteros, al finalizar el ciclo for podrias hacer lo siguiente

```
int id = 0;        
Random random = new Random();
List<Integer> numeros = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {
  id = Integer.valueOf(jTable1.getValueAt(i, 0).toString());
  numeros.add(id);
}

int numeroRandom = random.nextInt(numeros.size()); //Obtengo un index random usando el size del array numeros
int idRandom = numeros.get(numeroRandom); //obtengo el id random.
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias a ti tambien por tomarte el tiempo de ayudarme.